# Azure B2C using outdated version of JQuery (version 1.10.2)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We had an external code review and security check done for our product. One of the items highlighted was Azure B2C's use of old version of JQuery (version used by B2C is 1.10.2). We were wondering if there is a plan by Microsoft to update the JQuery version used by B2C?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we plan to ship page contracts soon (vote on the link below for updates) that allows us to change the versions more easily without breaking existing production environments. We will then make the updates as needed.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br

Answer (score -1):

For those that are also running into this issue, the page contracts mentioned by Parakh are implemented. To migrate to the new version, see this article section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout

To update these versions, edit the **TrustFrameworkPolicy>BuildingBlocks>ContentDefinitions>ContentDefinition>DataUri** XML value in the **TrustFrameworkBase.xml** file.

An example using the latest version (at the time of writing this comment):

```xml
<ContentDefinitions>

<!-- This content definition is to render an error page that displays unhandled errors. -->
<ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.2</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.3</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
    <Item Key="language.intro">Sign in</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.3</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
    <Item Key="language.intro">Sign up</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.7</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.11</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.11</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.11</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.11</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>

</ContentDefinitions>
```

Note that this example might use pages you don't need, to see which pages you might or might not want to use, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#content-definition-ids

For more information about the latest versions, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#jquery-and-handlebars-versions

Comment: I ran into this issue because I based my custom policies on GitHub samples that seem to be outdated.